# put selective rows of 2 tables into 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**[Edit:]** I Edited My Question ; I Put Up Same Column Name initially in three tables..So question was becoming Confusing ..Apologize for That

I have 2 tables :

Table_1

```
[1stColumn] [2nd Column]
1            11
2            12
```

and Table_2

```
[1stColumn] [2nd Column]
1            21
2            22
```

What I want to show data like this

Third Table

```
[1stColumn] [2nd Column]
1            11            -----> (1st Row of 1st Table)
2            22            -----> (2nd Row of 2nd Table)
```

I have Tried this :

```
select t1.c2,t2.c2 from Table_1 t1 join Table_2 t2 on t1.c1=t2.c1 
where t1.c2='11' and t2.c2='22'
```

This wont work ..i Also Tried other join but that doesnt result what is required ...

Any Suggestion would be Helpful

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What determines which row from which of the first 2 tables goes into the third?  Is `c1` the primary key? What do you want if there's a key value in table 2 but not table 1, or vice versa?

Comment: yes ...Both table c1 column is primary key ...what i want that first row of first table and 2nd row of 2nd table will be out into third Table

Comment: What if the tables 1 and 2 have more than 2 rows each?  Is there a more general rule that should govern cases you haven't described?

Comment: table_1 and table_2 can have N Rows ... I want 2 records in table 3 ..First from table1 and 2nd from table_2 ..column structure of all 3 tables are same

Comment: What you're asking doesn't seem to make any sense. If there's always a Table_1.c1 for every Table_2.c1 then if you make a Table_3 such that Table_3.c1 = Table_1.c1 && Table_3.c2 = Table_2.c2 then Table_3 = Table_2. So what is the point of making Table_3?

Comment: I Edited My Question ; I Put Up Same Column Name initially in there tables..So question was becoming Confusing ..Apologize for That

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2 from Table_1 t1 where t1.c2 = '11'
union all
select t2.c1, t2.c2 from Table_2 t2 where t2.c2 = '22';
```

You can insert the values into a third table using `insert`.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote, or is it just malicious?

Comment: I just upvoted, because my guess from the limited information would have suggested a Union

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I misread your question. My eyes somehow just blithely interpreted 'row' as 'col'. I think I'm smelling what you're stepping in now. You could use modulo `%` to alternate selected rows while using `UNION ALL` inside an `INSERT`. It seems pretty complicated for such a simple task, but this is the only way I could figure how to make it alternate from `table_1` to `table_2` even when `c1` (which I'm assuming is your primary key) is non-contiguous. I'm sure this can be streamlined somehow by someone smarter than me.

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (c1,c2)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT rownum, c2 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, c2 
    FROM ( SELECT @row :=0) r, table_1 
  ) ranked 
  WHERE rownum % 2 = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rownum, c2 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, c2 
    FROM ( SELECT @row :=0) r, table_2 
  ) ranked 
  WHERE rownum % 2 = 0) AS dt;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ae53/1), note the deletion of a table_2 record